# Does /proc/[pid]/status always use kB?

Tags: memory, proc

Particularly, does `proc` always list the VmRSS value in `kB`? I can't find a solid answer on the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), although it appears that it sticks to one unit.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it's always in kB. KiB (1024-bytes, not 1000) to be exact.

At least in Linux 4.0 (and this code has been largely unchanged since at least April 2005—that's when Linus switched to `git`, and I don't care to check back further) that output comes from [`task_mem` in `fs/proc/task_mmu.c`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/proc/task_mmu.c?id=39a8804455fb23f09157341d3ba7db6d7ae6ee76#n22). Excerpting a few lines:

```c
seq_printf(m,
    "VmPeak:\t%8lu kB\n"
    "VmSize:\t%8lu kB\n"
    "VmLck:\t%8lu kB\n"
    "VmPin:\t%8lu kB\n"
    "VmHWM:\t%8lu kB\n"
    "VmRSS:\t%8lu kB\n"
    "VmData:\t%8lu kB\n"
    "VmStk:\t%8lu kB\n"
    "VmExe:\t%8lu kB\n"
    "VmLib:\t%8lu kB\n"
    "VmPTE:\t%8lu kB\n"
    "VmPMD:\t%8lu kB\n"
    "VmSwap:\t%8lu kB\n",
    hiwater_vm << (PAGE_SHIFT-10),
    ⋮
);
```

Not sure if you can read C, but that "kB" is hardcoded there. There is no logic to output any other unit.

Comment: Does the same hold for `/proc/meminfo`? `man 5 proc` isn't exactly clear here.

Comment: @olejorgenb yep, that's hard-coded as kB as well. Look in `fs/proc/meminfo.c`. (And please send a patch to the manpage to clarify.)